# AngularJS activetab - Have multiple active links

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a single-page angular app that has navigation consisting of a series of primary section links and sub-menus for each of these.

I've been able to use activetabs with routeProvider to get the primary section links active, but how can I have the sub-page link also given an active class at the same time when on that page.

So for example, when on 'page1' a page within the 'section1' section, both the section1 and page1 buttons have an active class?

I can add the same ng-class attribute to the sub-page links, but obviously that means they'll all have the active class when you're on any page in the parent section. From what I've seen angular only supports a top level of active navigation links and not nesting.

-

Current app.js example:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider    
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController as main',
        activetab: 'home'
    })

    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController as main',
        activetab: 'home'
    })

    .when('/newPayroll', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/page2.html',
        controller: 'page2controller as page2',
        activetab: 'section2'
    })

    .when('/employeesList', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/page3.html',
        controller: 'page3controller as page3',
        activetab: 'section3'
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you to take a look at  [Ui router](https://ui-router.github.io/). It will help you to deal with views, nested views in a way you can't imagine.

And to answer your question, you can define any logic you want to set an active state for a buttons or anything by playing with ng-class. Just make some logic in your controller to check something and set it as the condition with ng-class.

That can be a url check with [$location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) or something else in your data.
Here's a link that will help you how to use ng-class in a lot of way to achieve what you want:
 https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

Hope it'll help you